# PHP Form not sending data [Wordpress]

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I'm developing a plugin for wordpress and inside a function i have a form which is included in a page!

The thing is, when i click the update button, the form doesn't send data and i get the form again (not updated) when i should get a message!

My code:

```
echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"". str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . "\">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Nume</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"nume\" value='".$data->name."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Departament</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"dep\" value='". $data->dep."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>An</td><td>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"an\" id=\"an\" value='".$data->anfac."'>
                            <span style=\"margin:0 5px;\">Edit</span>
                            <select name=\"anv\" id=\"anv\">
                                <option value=\"Anul I\">Anul I</option>'
                                <option value=\"Anul II\">Anul II</option>
                                <option value=\"Anul III\">Anull III</option>
                                <option value=\"Anul IV\">Anul IV</option>
                                <option value=\"Master Anul I\">Master Anul I</option>
                                <option value=\"Master Anul II\">Master Anul II</option>
                            </select>
                    <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery(\"#anv\").change(function(){
                            var valoare = jQuery(this).val();
                            jQuery(\"#an\").val(valoare);
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
                    </td></tr>




                    <tr><td>Grupa</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"grupa\" value='". $data->grupa ."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Telefon</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"tel\" value='". $data->telefon."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value='".$data->mail."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Facebook</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"fb\" value='".$data->fb."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Twitter</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"tw\" value='".$data->tw."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>LinkedIn</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"linked\" value='". $data->li."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Freelancer</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"freel\" value='".$data->freel."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Blog</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"blog\" value='". $data->site."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Membru din anul</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"memyear\" value='".$data->an."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Functii in LSE</td><td><textarea name=\"memfct\" id=\"\" cols=\"30\" rows=\"10\" value='".$data->fct."'>".$data->fct."</textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Evenimente</td><td><textarea name=\"evlse\" id=\"\" cols=\"30\" rows=\"10\" value='".$data->ev."'>".$data->ev,"</textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Skills</td><td><textarea name=\"skills\" id=\"\" cols=\"30\" rows=\"10\" value='".$data->skills."'>". $data->skills."</textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Avatar</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"avatar\" value='".$data->av ."'></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>CV</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"cv\" value='".$data->cv."'></td></tr>

                    <input type=\"hidden\" value='".$data->id."' name=\"id\">
                    <tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" name=\"update1234\"></td></tr>
                </table>

            </form>";
```

and the data "catcher" :

```
elseif (isset($_POST['update1234'])) {

        $nume = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nume']);
        $dep = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dep']);
        $an = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['an']);
        $grupa = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['grupa']);
        $tel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tel']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $fb = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fb']);
        $tw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tw']);
        $linked = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['linked']);
        $freel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['freel']);
        $blog = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['blog']);
        $memyear = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['memyear']);
        $fct = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['memfct']);
        $evlse = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['evlse']);
        $skills = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skills']);
        $avatar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['avatar']);
        $cv = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cv']);
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        $editlink = generate_edit_link();

        $sql ="UPDATE $lmdisp_table_name
                SET `".$lmdisp_nume."`= '".$nume."',
                `".$lmdisp_departament."` = '".$dep."',
                `".$lmdisp_an."` = '".$an."',
                `".$lmdisp_grupaserie."` = '".$grupa."',
                `".$lmdisp_tel."` = '".$tel."' ,
                `".$lmdisp_email."` = '".$email."',
                `".$lmdisp_fb."` = '".$fb."',
                `".$lmdisp_tw."` = '".$tw."',
                `".$lmdisp_linked."` = '".$linked."',
                `".$lmdisp_freel."` = '".$freel."',
                `".$lmdisp_blog."` = '".$blog."',
                `".$lmdisp_memyear."` = '".$memyear."',
                `".$lmdisp_fctlse."` = '".$fct."',
                `".$lmdisp_evlse."` = '".$evlse."',
                `".$lmdisp_skills."` = '".$skills."',
                `".$lmdisp_avatar."` = '".$avatar."',
                `".$lmdisp_cv."` = '".$cv."',
                `".$lmdisp_editlink."` = '".$editlink."'
            WHERE  `".$lmdisp_id."` = '".$id."'";

        if ($wpdb->query($sql)) {
            echo "Date modificate";
        } else {
            echo "S-a produs o eroare";
        }

            $wpdb->show_errors();
            $wpdb->print_error();
        } 

        else {
        echo 'Nu ar trebui sa fii aici';
    }
```

Comment: Nothing! Sorry. I forgot to mention..

Answer (score 1):

I tested the provided example and everything is ok, the form is sent. The only thing I noticed is that the 'catcher' example is a continuation of if-elseif block so it is possible that it is a logical error, and the first block is executed again. Try:

```
if ( isset($_POST['update1234']) ) {

    // save data

} else {

    // render form
}
```

Comment: I've tryied that but then i figured it out. I should have check first for $_POST['update'], and if that wasn't set to check the other if condition (which was if a GET var is set). The link remains the same after submit and that is why my function never got to the elseif(isset($_post...)) because the first were returning true... Anyway, thank you!:D

Comment: Then it seems that I guess where the problem is, no problem :)